# Error in rails server command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As suggested in a course on Coursera.org, while installing rails I used a command: `rails server` and got the following error:

```
**C:\Ruby On Rails\test_install>rails server
C:/Ruby On Rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:40:in `exec': No such file or directory - "C:/Ruby On Rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/ruby.exe" (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby On Rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:40:in `block in exec_app'
        from C:/Ruby On Rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:35:in `loop'
        from C:/Ruby On Rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:35:in `exec_app'                                             from C:/Ruby On Rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'                                             from C:/Ruby On Rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby On Rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby On Rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby On Rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/exe/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby On Rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/rails:22:in `load'                                                                                                       from C:/Ruby On Rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
C:\Ruby On Rails\test_install>**
```

I use windows 10.

Comment: `No such file or directory - "C:/Ruby On Rails/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/ruby.exe"` check your Ruby installation.

Comment: I'm not a PC user but I think PCs will give you problems if you use a folder name with spaces in it like Ruby on Rails. I'd change it to something like rubyonrails.